# Comparing hashes and delete files with same hash in powershell not working

Tags: powershell, hash

I am doing a script that identifies the hashes of all the files of a path (and recursively). This is alright.

My problem comes when, after I have identified which hashes are the same, I want to save them into an array so later I can delete these files that have the same Hash (if I want to), or just print the duplicate files. And I have been all afternoon and evening trying to figure out how to do it. 
My code at the moment:

```
Write-Host "Write a path: "
$UserInput=Read-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path $UserInput -Recurse

#Get-FileHash cmdlet to get the hashes
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $UserInput -Recurse | where { !$_.PSIsContainer }
$files | % {(Get-FileHash -Path $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5)}



#Creating an array for all the values and an array for the duplicates
$originals=@()
$copies=@()

 #grouping the hashes that are duplicated cmdlet Group-Object:
$Duplicates = Get-ChildItem -Path $UserInput -Recurse -File |Group {($_|Get-FileHash).Hash} |Where Count -gt 1
foreach($FileGroup in $Duplicates)
{
    Write-Host "These files share hash : $($FileGroup.Name)"
    $FileGroup.Group.FullName |Write-Host
    $copies+=$Duplicates

}
```

So the last part "$copies+=$Duplicates" does not work properly.

In the begining I was thinking of saving the first file in the "original" array. If the second one has the same hash, save that 2nd in the "copies" array. But I am not sure if I can do that in the 1st part of the script when getting the hashes.

After that, the second array would have the duplicates, so it would be easy to delete them from the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need to use `Get-ChildItem` once, once you have all the files you can create a hash for them and then group the hashes to find duplicates. See my example code below:

```
Write-Host "Write a path: "
$UserInput=Read-Host

#Get-FileHash cmdlet to get the hashes
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $UserInput -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript { !$_.PSIsContainer }
$hashes = $files | ForEach-Object -Process {Get-FileHash -Path $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5}

$duplicates = $hashes | Group-Object -Property Hash | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Count -gt 1}

foreach($duplicate in $duplicates)
{
    Write-Host -Object "These files share hash : $($duplicate.Group.Path -join ', ')"

    # delete first duplicate
    # Remove-Item -Path $duplicate.Group[0].Path -Force -WhatIf

    # delete second duplicate
    # Remove-Item -Path $duplicate.Group[1].Path -Force -WhatIf

    # delete all duplicates except the first
    # foreach($duplicatePath in ($duplicate.Group.Path | Select-Object -Skip 1))
    # {
    #     Remove-Item -Path $duplicatePath -Force -WhatIf
    # }
}
```

Uncomment the code at the end to delete duplicates based on your preferences and when you're ready to delete files make sure you also remove the `-WhatIf` parameter.

This is the output i receive from the above command if i uncomment out the "delete all duplicates except the first"

```
Write a path: 
H:\
These files share hash : H:\Rename template 2.csv, H:\Rename template.csv
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "H:\Rename template.csv".
```

Comment: So you can actually delete the duplicates because you are using othe hashes and duplicates as "objects", right? In my case I do the search recursively (so I get all files, and the files from directories, etc). I've tried it and it does not do it recursive, so might it be only adding the -recursive part and that's it, right?

I have also tried the "Delete all duplicates except the 1st one" and it does not delete the actual files! 

Also, the "duplicates" is an array, right?

Comment: Yes you will need the `Recurse` parameter, i was testing without it and forgot to add it back. Do you receive any error messages when you run the code? I am able to run it successfully (with the `-Recurse` parameter.

Comment: Now it works perfectly fine! Well, it says it has deleted the files but when I go to the directory to look if the files have been deleted, The message pops out that they have been but they are not.

Comment: Make sure you have removed the `WhatIf` parameter when you want to actually delete the files, if you leave it on the line it will say `Performing action "Delete" on "C:\Folder1\Duplicate1.txt"` but it won't actually delete anything.

Comment: Yes! I noticed it quite fast and removed it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would hardlinking be achieved by adding after Remove-Item in "delete all duplicates except the first": New-Item -ItemType HardLink -Name {file from $duplicate.Group[1].Path} -Value $duplicate.Group[0].Path

Answer (score 3):

I think you should filter the items. I did it and I have a list with only one item of duplicate files and a list with all duplicated files.

> You can use the **SHA1** algorithm instead of **MD5**
>
> SHA1 is much more faster than the MD5 algorithm

```
$fileHashes = Get-ChildItem -Path $myFilePath -Recurse -File | Get-Filehash -Algorithm SHA1
$duplicates = $fileHashes | Group hash | ? {$_.count -gt 1} | % {$_.Group} 

$uniqueItems = @{}
$doubledItems = @()

foreach($item in $duplicates) {
  
  if(-not $uniqueItems.ContainsKey($item.Hash)){
    $uniqueItems.Add($item.Hash,$item)
  }else{
    $doubledItems += $item
  }
}

# all duplicates files
$doubledItems

# Remove the duplicate files
# $doubledItems | % {Remove-Item $_.path} -Verbose

# one of the duplicate files
$uniqueItems
```

Set the seach root folder

```
$myFilePath = ''
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great! How would you then delete for example, all the files in the array? Not deleting the array nor the elements in the array, but the actual files!

Comment: $doubledItems | % {Remove-Item $_.path}